# Workflows feature not listed in Site Collection Features - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I was just given administrator access to my company's SharePoint 2010 site, and I need to implement an Approval workflow.  This is an out-of-the-box workflow, and it is not currently available to me.  The only help I have been able to find after exhaustive web searches is to navigate to Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Site Collection Features and activate the Workflows feature, which should be the last feature in the list.

The problem is, there is *no* Workflows feature in my top-level site's Site Collection Feature.  There is only a "Three-state workflow" feature for workflows, and the Three-state workflow is the only one available.  What would keep the "Workflows" feature from being displayed in the Site Collection Features list?  I need to activate this feature to get access to the OOTB workflows and their functionality.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using **SharePoint Foundation** ?
The only workflow feature available for fondation is the Three State workflow. The Workflows Feature (out of the box) is only in Standard and Enterprise

Comment: Sorry for the waste of time! I contacted the overall SharePoint Administrator and that site was indeed on SharePoint Foundation 2010.  I have been granted access to the SharePoint 2013 Enterprise sites and will try my workflows there instead.  Thanks Nico!